# Why this Angular 2 drag & drop example prevents scrolling?

Tags: angular, scroll, drag-and-drop

I found an example **drag & drop** code for **Angular 2 app** and here it's plunkr code :

**plnkr.co/edit/wXLvaOlD4GVW2hg7utGx?p=preview**

It works perfectly (when you remove the **br** tags).

But I have to use browser's default scroll behavior while dragging element. This example prevents scrolling while dragging.

**How should I use this example with scroll?**

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement the angular  host for example like :

```
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event']) onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) {      
  window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX); 
}
```

Comment: I was seeking such a solution you just gave, and the answer had me in the correct direction, yet what you are writing is very confusing. what is curXPos and e.pageX?